# How to keep selected value in a dropdown box using JQUERY?

Tags: php, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery

Hi am using a jquery code like this

```
$(".selfont").change(function(event){

$('#dav').val();

window.location ='?davQ=' + $('#dav').val() + '&pathogenQ=' + $('#pathogen').val() + '&topicQ=' + $('#topicF').val() ;

});
```

I want to keep the dropdown value selected by the user in each dropdown boxes. But at present the value is not the one selected by the user, its always showing the first value. How can I set the dropdown field with value selected by the user using jquery? Please help me.

My first select box code is like below

```
<select name="dav" id="dav" style="width: 275px" class='selfont' >
<option value='' class=''>Select one</option>
                        <?php

                                $test = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT DataVersion FROM olivesdeptable ORDER BY DataVersion DESC");
                                 $i=1;
                                 while($numval=mysql_fetch_array($test))
                                 {
                                          print "<option value=\"".$numval['DataVersion']."\">".$numval['DataVersion']."</option>";
                                          $i=$i+1;
                                  }
                          ?>

                    </select>
```

Even if we select value it will show as "Select one" in the field.

javascript code for dropdown fields

```
<script type="text/javascript">

if (document.getElementById("dav").selectedIndex < 1)
{
document.getElementById('pathogen').selectedIndex = "";
document.getElementById('pathogen').disabled = true;
}

if (document.getElementById("pathogen").selectedIndex < 1)
{
document.getElementById('topicF').selectedIndex = "";
document.getElementById('topicF').disabled = true;
}

if (document.getElementById("topicF").selectedIndex < 1)
{
document.getElementById('ind').selectedIndex = "";
document.getElementById('ind').disabled = true;
}

if (document.getElementById("ind").selectedIndex < 1)
{
document.getElementById('subind').selectedIndex = "";
document.getElementById('subind').disabled = true;
}

if (document.getElementById("subind").selectedIndex < 1)
{
document.getElementById('countryR').selectedIndex = "";
document.getElementById('countryRF').options.length = 0;
document.getElementById('countryRF').selectedIndex = "";
document.getElementById('countryR').disabled = true;
document.getElementById('countryRF').disabled = true;
}

</script>
```

even the value is updated, the second drop down box is showing as disabled ?

Next dropdown field markup is as below

```
 <select name="pathogen" id="pathogen" style="width: 275px" class='selfont' >
    <option value=''>Select one</option>
                            <?php

                                    $test = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT Pathogen FROM olivesdeptable where DataVersion='$davQ' ORDER BY Pathogen ASC");
                                    $i=1;
                                     while($numval=mysql_fetch_array($test))
                                     {
                                              print "<option value=\"".$numval['Pathogen']."\">".$numval['Pathogen']."</option>";
                                              $i=$i+1;
                                      }
                              ?>

                    </select>
```

only first dropbox value is working  for next dropbox value is storing in url but in page the value shows as 'Select one' ? Please help to sort

Comment: u need to show ur html markup, or can u setup a fiddle for us, http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: the url is updated with value selected in listbox, but in listbox its showing the first value "Select one" ?

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#dav').val(getURLParameter('davQ'));

            $('#pathogenQ').val(getURLParameter('pathogenQ'));

            $('#topicQ').val(getURLParameter('topicQ'));

            $(".selfont").change(function (event) {
                 window.location = '?davQ=' + $('#dav').val() + '&pathogenQ=' + $('#pathogen').val() + '&topicQ=' + $('#topicF').val();
            });

            function getURLParameter(name) {
            return decodeURI((RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(location.search) || [, null])[1]);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the code, its working fine, but I got a javascript code running for fields which I have been updated above in my question. Even after the first field is updated the second one is still showing as disabled? Is there any modification needed ? pls help... thanks in advance.

Comment: everytime value selected in dropdown box its updated in window.location parameter and next select option is enabled with respect to first.

Comment: **some list values contain + and % sign, while selecting this its shows error as "The URI to be decoded is not a valid encoding". The code is working thank you very much. How can I correct this minor error ? @ThulasiRam**

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

  $test = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT DataVersion FROM olivesdeptable ORDER BY DataVersion DESC");
  $i=1;
  $selected = '';
  // make compare with the value you want to select with the parameter form url
  // here I assume $_GET['davQ'] holds the value to $numval['DataVersion']
  if($_GET['davQ'] == $numval['DataVersion']) $selected = 'selected';
  while($numval=mysql_fetch_array($test))
  {
     echo "<option value=\"".$numval['DataVersion']."\" $selected>".$numval['DataVersion']."</option>";
     $i=$i+1;
  }
?>
```